# Implement SelectedItem for CarouselViewControl

Tags: xamarin.forms

Implement SelectedItem(like on ListView) for CarouselViewControl

tried PositionSelected and PositionSelectedCommand Doesn't work as it gives on position of item selected in the list.

ViewModel Implementation:

```
private void LoadData(IEnumerable<Model> myCourse)
    {
        this.Items.Clear();
        if (myCourse != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in myCourse)
            {
                var itemToAdd = new Model
                {
                    ActiviyId = item.ActiviyId,                        
                };
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    this.Items.Add(itemToAdd);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand<Model> CourseSelectedCommand => new DelegateCommand<Model>(async (Param) => await this.OnCourseItemSelectedCommand(Param));

    private async Task OnCourseItemSelectedCommand(Model model)
    {
        var navigationParams = new NavigationParameters();
        navigationParams.Add("ActivityID", model.ActiviyId);
        await this.navigationService.NavigateAsync("ModulePage", navigationParams, true, false);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to add command with parameters. I keep getting null as my parameters.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test with it?